# How to make an automatic slideshow with buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, slider, slideshow

I created a automatic slideshow by using html , css and javascript but the next/previous and dot buttons are not working. When I made them work , slideshow becomes unautomatic. I added buttons to its cshtml file so nothing's missing. CSS file works perfectly as well.  What is missing in my code ? Any help will be appreciated.

*Javascript Code*

```
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
var responsiveSlider = function () {

    var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
    var sliderWidth = slider.offsetWidth;
    var slideList = document.getElementById("slideWrap");
    var count = 1;
    var items = slideList.querySelectorAll("li").length;
    var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
    var next = document.getElementById("next");

    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
        sliderWidth = slider.offsetWidth;
    });
    var prevSlide = function () {
        if (count > 1) {
            count = count - 2;
            slideList.style.left = "-" + count * sliderWidth + "px";
            count++;
        }
        else if (count = 1) {
            count = items - 1;
            slideList.style.left = "-" + count * sliderWidth + "px";
            count++;
        }
    };
    var nextSlide = function () {
        if (count < items) {
            slideList.style.left = "-" + count * sliderWidth + "px";
            count++;
        }
        else if (count = items) {
            slideList.style.left = "0px";
            count = 1;
        }
    };
    next.addEventListener("click", function () {
        nextSlide();
    });
    prev.addEventListener("click", function () {
        prevSlide();
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        nextSlide()
    }, 5000);
};
window.onload = function () {
    responsiveSlider();
}
```

```
@using SliderBannerProject.Model.Entity
@model List<Table_Slider>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/TestLayout.cshtml";
}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Content/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script defer src="~/Content/Script.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <div class="mySlides w3-animate-fading">
            <div class="numbertext">@item.ID</div>
            <img src="@item.SliderPhoto" style="width:100%" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="text" id="text1" >@item.SliderInfo1</div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="text" id="update">
                <p style="margin-bottom:-50px" >
                    <a href="/Test/UpdateInfo/@item.ID" id="update1">
                        Update Slider
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            }       
    </div>
    <br>   
</body>
<!-- The dots/circles -->
<br />
<div style="text-align:center">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(@item.ID)"></span>
    }
</div>

<br />
<div style="text-align:center">
    <a href="/Test/AddInfo" class="btn btn-warning" style="text-align:center">Add New Slider Photo</a>
</div>
</html>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box

}

 
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    animation: slide 10s infinite;
}


.mySlides {
    display: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    animation: slide 10s infinite;
}

#text1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-display:swap;
    font-style:oblique;
    color:gray;
    
}

#update {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#update1 {
  
    color: black;
    
}


.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

    /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
    .prev:hover, .next:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }

.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}


.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 5s ease;
}

    .active, .dot:hover {
        background-color: #717171;
    }


.fade {
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation: slide 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: 10
    }

    to {
        opacity: 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant html and css code as well? This makes it easier to test out your code.

Comment: @MeL I just added them

Answer (score 0):

```
let slideIndex = 1; 
let i;
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

auto();

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active"; 
}

function auto() {
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  setTimeout(auto, 10000);
}
```

Try this i found that on youtube, [here is the link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRE2Zge1rUI&t=439s)